# How to access an indexed property on a COM object from Powershell

Tags: com, powershell

I'm using Powershell to talk to the Windows 7 task scheduler service via COM through the [Task Scheduler 2.0 interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600(VS.85).aspx) (e.g. ITaskDefinition). I want to pull out a particular trigger from the [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381325(VS.85).aspx) collection on ITaskDefinition. It appears that the proper way to extract a particular trigger is through the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381894(VS.85).aspx) property, which is an indexed property.

My first try looks something like this:

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$folder = $sched.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask("some task")
$triggers = $task.Definition.Triggers
$trigger = $triggers[0]
```

However, the last line fails with this message:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.__ComObject.
```

I've tried some other variations on this theme, e.g. `$triggers.Item(0)`, all with no luck. I'm guessing this has to do with `$trigger` being a COM object, because I think indexed properties work fine on other types.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Item does work. You have to use Item() instead of Item[] and indices are 1-based.

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$folder = $sched.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask("Update Bin Dir")
$triggers = $task.Definition.Triggers
$triggers.Item(1)

Type               : 2
Id                 : 67a9fad4-462f-43d9-ab71-6e9b781966e6
Repetition         : System.__ComObject
ExecutionTimeLimit : 
StartBoundary      : 2007-07-02T05:30:00
EndBoundary        : 
Enabled            : True
DaysInterval       : 1
RandomDelay        :
```

Using an enumerator also works if you don't need to access by index:

```
foreach ($trigger in $triggers) { $trigger }
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work also. Still hoping someone knows of a more direct way, though.

Comment: Yeah this is bugging me now. :-)

Comment: You know, along this same note the following seems to work:
foreach($trigger in $task.Definition.Triggers) {$trigger}

Comment: Very nice; that's what I get for not reading the docs closely enough. Thanks for the effort in tracking this down.

Comment: Been doing .NET for so long, the 1-based index thing stumped me for a while.  Thanks to x0n for help on that aspect of the problem.

Comment: I have an indexed-property in the EnvDTE: `ProjectItem.FileNames`, however whenever I do `ForEach($fn in $projectItem.FileNames) { Write-Host $fn }` I get this output: "`string FileNames (short) {get} `".

Comment: When I use `For($i=1;$i -le $projectItem.FileNames.Length; $i++) { Write-Host $projectItem.FileNames($i) }` it works! It's weird how the `.Length` property exists despite `FileNames` not being a collection object itself.

Answer (score 3):

On my system, it looks like there is only one trigger being returned for some tasks. You might try forcing it to return in an array.

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$folder = $sched.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask("some task")
$triggers = @($task.Definition.Triggers)
$trigger = $triggers[0]
```

Comment: Cool, this seems like a good workaround. I'm hoping someone will know how to do it "properly", but this will get me going for now.

Comment: Awesome workaround. I was trying to cast it to an array, but totally forgot this is the right way to do it for objects like these. Thanks!